# How to see older questions I have asked?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, profile-page

When I go to my profile I have the "view more" link close to questions section. But I see no paging on there. How can I see older questions I have asked and which aren't on that page any more?

Comment: Looks OK to me: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1956207/hikari?tab=questions

Comment: Look at the bottom of the page, to the right.

Comment: You wouldnt happen to have a scroll bar do you? You may have to scroll to the right.

Comment: Lol sorry! I have a horizontal scroll and didn't see it on the right :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the bottom-right side of [your questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1956207/hikari?tab=questions) you will see the pagination.

> [image]

Click on the item I've circled and it will take you to the second page of questions, or click on the "next" to the right to take you to the (surprise surprise) next page.